# How to merge a daily and an intra-day XTS object?

Tags: r, xts, quantitative-finance

I am trying to merge a daily `XTS` object (indexed by `POSIXCT`, `format = "%d/%m/%Y"`) with an intraday `XTS` object (indexed by `POSIXCT`, `format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"`).

The intra day object doesn't have a midnight (`00:00`) index, but by default the merge creates one and adds the daily variable to that observation.

How can I merge the daily into the intraday, but merge to the nearest index, so I do not create a bunch of `00:00` observations in my data?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its the best solution, but I ended up filtering out any indexes that matched in both data

```
x <- x[!(index(x) %in% index(y))]
```